# jQuery UI Accordion with sections wrapped in DIVs

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I've successfully implemented an accordion as outlined [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/), but would like to wrap each section in a div, so my structure would be as follows:

```
<div id="accordion">
<div class="wrap">
<h3><a href="#">Header 1</a></h3>
<div>Collapsible content 1</div>
</div><!-- end wrap -->
<div class="wrap">
<h3><a href="#">Header 2</a></h3>
<div>Collapsible content 2</div>
</div><!-- end wrap -->
<div class="wrap">
<h3><a href="#">Header 3</a></h3>
<div>Collapsible content 3</div>
</div><!-- end wrap -->
</div>
```

Is this possible using the accordion functionality provided in jQuery UI? As of now, if I try to build it this way, it attempts to treat the `<div class="wrap">` as the section header.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Changing the header option seems alright.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-header

```
$(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion(
         { header: '> div.wrap > h3' }
        );
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Quincy/RCXwz/

Comment: is it possible we can addclass to wrapper if it is active and remove class if it is not active?